# Unregister uwp background task

Tags: uwp, background-task

I register a background task and I try to unregister it again when a certain setting is deactivated. But I only found information about register and scheduling tasks. Is there no way to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
var tasks = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks;
            foreach(var task in tasks)
            {
                // You can check here for the name
                string name = task.Value.Name;

                task.Value.Unregister(true);
            }
```